# Jquery Mobile Ajax Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm have a Jquery Mobile page where I'm using AJAX to pull data into listviews that are inside of collapsible widgets. In many cases, I have 10+ collapsible widgets each containing a listview.

When I open a collapsible widget, the AJAX function is called and the data is pulled in. This works just fine.

However, I'm experiencing a problem when I open 2 collapsible widgets without closing one of them:

1) When the second collapsible widget is opened, the AJAX function fires for both widgets. I don't want the AJAX function to fire on the first-opened widget.

Thanks in advance for your help. My code is below.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<title>Edit Kits</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Auer.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="editkits" class="type-interior">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Edit Kits</h1>
<a href="SPI_SearchLink" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-left">Home</a>
<a data-rel="back" data-icon="back" class="ui-btn-right">Back</a>
<div class="header-sub">
<div class="ui-bar center-text"><img src="images/logo.png" id="logo" alt="spi_Cname"/></div>
</div>
<div data-role="navbar" class="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="SPI_TOCLink" data-theme="c">TOC</a></li>

<!-- SPI_HTML_ShowSearchMenu -->
<li><a href="SPI_SearchLink" data-theme="c">Search</a></li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_ShowSearchMenu -->

<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowKits -->
<li><a href="SPI_KitsLink" class="ui-btn-active" data-theme="c">Kits</a></li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowKits -->

<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowSales -->
<li><a href="SPI_SalesLink" data-theme="c">SPI_SalesMenuText</a></li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowSales -->

<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowOrderPlacement -->
<li><a href="SPI_ShopingCartLink" data-theme="c">Cart</a></li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowOrderPlacement -->
</ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">

<!-- SPI_No_Kit_Message -->
<div class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e center-text">
<br>
<h2>You have no saved Kits.</h2>
<p>To create a kit, add products to your shopping
cart and click "save as kit" on the menu at the bottom of your display.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- SPI_No_Kit_Message -->

<!-- SPI_HTML_HdrOnlyKit -->
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-content-theme="d">
<h3 id="SPI_KitId" class="kit">SPI_KitName SPI_KitNote</h3>
<div class="kitid"></div>
</div>
<!-- SPI_HTML_HdrOnlyKit -->

<!-- SPI_HTML_Kit -->
<form name="SPI_KitFormName" method="post" action="WebCatPageServer.exe">
<input name="Action" type="hidden" value="Not_Set" />
<input name="IsAjax" type="hidden" value="Yes" />
<input name="KitId" type="hidden" value="SPI_KitId" />
<input name="SearchTerm" type="hidden" value="Not_Set" />
<ul data-role="listview" id="list" data-inset="true" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="d">
<!-- SPI_HTML_Kit_Product1 -->
<li><a href="javascript:document.ShoppingCart.Action.value='ItemLookup';document.ShoppingCart.SearchTerm.value='SPI_CartLookupPartNum';document.ShoppingCart.submit();">
<!-- SPI_KitProdItemNum -->
<h2>SPI_KitProdPartNum</h2>
<!-- SPI_KitProdItemNum -->
<p class="description">SPI_KitProdDesc</p>
<p><input type="text"  name="SPI_KitOrdQtyFieldName" onBlur="clickrecall(this,'0')" tabindex="SPI_KitOrdQtyTabIndex" value="SPI_KitProdQty"  onfocus="document.SPI_KitFormName.Action.value='Recalc_Kit';SPI_KitOrdQtyFieldName.select()"/></p>
<p>Unit Price: SPI_KitProdPrice</p>
<p>Ext. Price: <span class="price">SPI_KitProdExtPrice</span></p>
</a>
<!-- SPI_HTML_KitsAllowEdit -->
<a href="javascript:document.SPI_KitFormName.SPI_KitOrdQtyFieldName.value='DEL';document.SPI_KitFormName.Action.value='Recalc_Kit';document.SPI_KitFormName.submit();">Delete</a> 
<!-- SPI_HTML_KitsAllowEdit -->
</li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Kit_Product1 -->
<!-- SPI_HTML_Kit_Product2 -->
<li><a href="javascript:document.ShoppingCart.Action.value='ItemLookup';document.ShoppingCart.SearchTerm.value='SPI_CartLookupPartNum';document.ShoppingCart.submit();">
<!-- SPI_KitProdItemNum -->
<h2>SPI_KitProdPartNum</h2>
<!-- SPI_KitProdItemNum -->
<p class="description">SPI_KitProdDesc</p>
<p><input type="text"  name="SPI_KitOrdQtyFieldName" onBlur="clickrecall(this,'0')" tabindex="SPI_KitOrdQtyTabIndex" value="SPI_KitProdQty"  onfocus="document.SPI_KitFormName.Action.value='Recalc_Kit';SPI_KitOrdQtyFieldName.select()"/></p>
<p>Unit Price: SPI_KitProdPrice</p>
<p>Ext. Price: <span class="price">SPI_KitProdExtPrice</span></p>
</a>
<!-- SPI_HTML_KitsAllowEdit -->
<a href="javascript:document.SPI_KitFormName.SPI_KitOrdQtyFieldName.value='DEL';document.SPI_KitFormName.Action.value='Recalc_Kit';document.SPI_KitFormName.submit();">Delete</a> 
<!-- SPI_HTML_KitsAllowEdit -->
</li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Kit_Product2 -->
</ul>
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
<a href="javascript:document.SPI_KitFormName.Action.value='Delete_Kit';document.SPI_KitFormName.submit();" data-role="button" data-theme="c">Delete Kit</a>
<!-- SPI_HTML_KitsAllowEdit -->
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:document.EditKits1.Action.value='Recalc_Kit';" data-role="button" data-theme="c">Save Kit</a>
<!-- SPI_HTML_KitsAllowEdit -->
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:document.SPI_KitFormName.Action.value='ClearQtys_Kit';document.SPI_KitFormName.submit();" data-role="button" data-theme="c">Clear Qty's</a>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowOrderPlacement -->
<a href="javascript:document.SPI_KitFormName.Action.value='AddKitToCart';document.SPI_KitFormName.submit();" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Add to Cart</a>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowOrderPlacement -->
</div>
</form>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Kit -->

</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" id="footer" data-position="fixed">
<h4>&copy; Auer Steel 2011</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("h3.kit").live('click', function () {
    $(".kitid").empty().html('<img src="images/load.gif" />');
    var kitid = this.id;
    var url = 'http://68.188.40.182/WebCat/WebCatPageServer.exe?AJAX&Action=Open_Kit&KitID=' + kitid;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: ajaxCallDone,
        complete: function () {},
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error type :" + errorThrown + " Error message :" + XMLHttpRequest.responseXML + " textStatus: " + textStatus);
        }
    });

    function ajaxCallDone(data) {
        $(".kitid").html(data);
        try {
            $('ul#list').listview('refresh');
        } catch (e) {
            $('ul#list').listview();
        }
        jQuery('#editkits').page("destroy").page();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are always global, i.e. $(".kitid") will always select ALL elements with a class of kitid.

What you want is to limit the scope of your ajax to the currently clicked item, passed by the this property (you already get it's id but that's about it!).

You need to use that to then only clear/ajax/update the one content the user clicked on, instead of acting on all of them...